# dropdown z-Index Issue

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with the dropdown menu on [this](https://www.timecode.ir/faq/) site.

as you see the `dropdown` showing behind the contents.
I added `z-index` in different places, but nothing changed!

update: It seems on firefox it shows correctly. the problem appears on chrome.

Comment: I see dropdowns correctly, above content.

**Theory**:
`Z-index` can be changed just for elements with `position` set to non-static (relative, fixed, absolute).

Comment: @panther I think it above on firefox. but in chrome its not.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 you are right. but I don't know how to show my problem without linking to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh, you mean the menu (I though selects over FAQ).

You try to set `z-index` to `header--tabbar`, but the parent is under content. You need to set z-index to `.wt-container` previous sibling, it means `header`. And of course, set `position` too.

style.css, line 778

```
.header {position: relative; z-index: 99}
```

Comment: It works fine. but could you tell me why the position is important here?

Comment: @D.JCode: z-index isn't applied when position is set to `static` (default value)... That's fact.